# Vocabulary Wordlist for the elementary school English

Tags: corpora, vocabulary

I am curious if there is a written English corpus that offers word frequency lists for the elementary stage vocabulary, i.e. K-5 grades? Something like [Dr. Edward Fry's *sight* words](http://www.sightwords.com/sight-words/fry/), which is updated in 1980s.

There is [COCA](http://www.wordfrequency.info/top5000.asp) and it has an up to date list, in 2010 I guess, of the most common general vocabulary. However, it does not offer a specialized list for the elementary stage.

Comment: Ask on https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it does not belong here, please move it into ELL